# Is alternating between push ups and pull ups everyday overtraining?

Tags: recovery, home-exercise, bodyweight, overtraining, interval-training

I've started working out consistently at home for the first time. My workouts include some daily exercises for improving posture (I have rounded shoulders and anterior pelvic tilt) and also some muscle building exercises.

Currently I'm doing push ups on one day then pull ups the next day, always alternating between the two. Not working out on weekends at all.

I know it's incredibly important to give your muscles enough time to recover. This is why I'm concerned about overtraining. Surely some muscles are involved in both push ups and pull ups and I wouldn't wanna deprive them of their recovery time.

Should I combine my exercises into one workout day and give them a full day of recovery or am I safe?

The benefit of splitting the workouts is that I'm able to put more energy into the exercises.

Comment: How many reps / sets are you doing?

Comment: @EricKaufman 5 sets of 10 really slow reps with whole range of motion for push ups, and 5 sets of as many pull ups as possible.

Comment: [This doesn't seem to be worry for Frank Medrano](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/92/aa/24/92aa242f030dd5f39e18b9afed57deae.jpg)

Comment: I think the best is to get started working. 21 days of workouts, shows a real change in habit and then start worrying about the best way to shape a body.

Comment: If you are only doing one exercise a day (5 reps) you will never get overtrained. Overtraining comes from pushing your personal limits over a very long time. As I do not know you, I don’t know your personal limit. But if you are a healthy (young) adult doing 5 reps of push / pull ups or any other exercise a day will never lead to overtraining.

Answer (score 3):

Overtraining is different for every person first of all.

Although to answer your question I believe you won't be Overtraining that way.

If you are looking for a serious workout routine to start with I can recommend the following which is free:

http://freebodybuildingworkoutprogram.com/thtdownload/

I do it myself and so far I enjoy doing it. The explanations are very easy to follow and every exercise is explained in detail with videos.

Check out the Substitute Exercises List if you lack the equipment for some exercises.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into that. I've actually had pretty good results doing what I do after just a few weeks. Arms and chest are my biggest priority right now. I might wanna start a proper plan to address all muscles in a few weeks though.

Comment: That's right. You should always aim to train your whole body to avoid any dysbalance. ;)